# Can't set path to jdk 11 in IntelIj-IDEA

Tags: java, intellij-idea, linux-mint

Linux Mint 20.1,

IntelIJ IDEA Community Edition 2020.3

I install Oracle jdk 11.

In terminal :

```
 java -version
    java version "11.0.10" 2021-01-19 LTS
    Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 18.9 (build 11.0.10+8-LTS-162)
    Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 18.9 (build 11.0.10+8-LTS-162, mixed mode)


echo $JAVA_HOME
/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-oracle

which java
/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-oracle/bin/java
```

In file etc/profile:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-oracle
export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
```

In terminal

```
ls /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-oracle/

    bin  conf  include  jmods  legal  lib  README.html  release
```

Nice.

Now I want to set path to jdk in IntelIj IDEA.

Go to File->Project Stucture->Add new SDK -> Add JDK

But I can't see path to jdk:

```
/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-oracle
```

[image]

As you can see it not show path : `/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-oracle/`

Comment: Err. You are looking for /usr/lib, but you search /lib?

Comment: @GhostCat No I search in usr/lib. I was updated my post

Comment: Now you are looking at /home/usr/lib which is again not the same as /usr/lib. Pay attention to exact full path you are pointing your IDE to.

Comment: @GhostCat Not help. Same result. I updated my post

Comment: What does `which java` say? You see, you EXPORTING JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/ doesnt mean that the path used there is really correct. Does a simple `ls /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64` work?

Comment: Show full listing of `/usr/lib/` the you see in IDE File Chooser dialog. And show the output from the `ls -la /usr/lib/jvm` in terminal. What user do you use to run IDE?

Comment: @Andrey I added my answer with solution

Comment: @GhostCat I founded solution. See my answer

Answer (score 1):

I fix the problem.

1. Uninstall IntelIJ IDEA
2. Install from official site (not from Software Manager)

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/installation-guide.html#snap

And now IDE show path `usr/lib/jvm/`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It's likely that you don't have permission to access that folder in intellij. First open intellij as root. If you can search the path that way then follow this steps, otherwise I have no idea what the problem might be.

Go to/usr/lib in the terminal and run this command

```
sudo chmod -R 755 jvm
```

That will give read and execution permissions to everyone in your PC for every file and folder in that path.

Comment: That is horrible advice. Starting IntelliJ as root once might create all kinds of files with ROOT permissions in your home directory. So when you come back as normal user later on, you run into all kinds of issues.